# how to find out wrong email id in mail using java

Tags: jakarta-mail

We will be sending automated emails through a mail box ,we will send an email with two to three emails in TO column and one or more emails in the CC column ,if i have a wrong email in the TO column in that mail box we will get a delivery report that email is wrong i need to write a program such that it will pick up the wrong email id

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading up on [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#bounce) and the [com.sun.mail.dsn](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/dsn/package-summary.html) package.  The [JavaMail Homepage](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) has all of the downloads you'll need.

You could also enable the [mail.smtp.reportsuccess](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) property per the documentation:

> When sending a message, detailed information on each address that fails is available in an SMTPAddressFailedException chained off the top level SendFailedException that is thrown. In addition, if the mail.smtp.reportsuccess property is set, an SMTPAddressSucceededException will be included in the list for each address that is successful. Note that this will cause a top level SendFailedException to be thrown even though the send was successful.